Does marker pigment have an effect on removability from whiteboards?
I've noticed that black Pentel MW86 markers for whiteboards tend to dry out quickly and are more difficult to remove compared to the other  pigments (colors) of the same brand. Does pigment have an effect on removability of ink?
And what is the best the material to clean a stain on a whiteboard?

I checked the components of a marker and as of now I found  that alcohol is the best yet it still preforms poorly , what materials should I consider to break down marker components ,how would one start an examination without trying things blindly ?

BTW, "black" pigments are often made from combinations of other colors -- whether that is the case for those markers or not, I don't know.

since I am new on this site I would appreciate some explanation on what's wrong in this question so that I can learn for the future , is it not considered chemistry ?  are the tags wrong  etc thanks for your time

There is nothing inherently wrong with the question. You may want to pay more attention to punctuation, formating, etc. See also the site help pages for guidance: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help

You can find more about the composition of the ink in such markers here: https://pentel.ca/msds_pdf/MSDS_MW-MARKERS.pdf

On second hand there might be a few reasons this is not getting a more positive reception. First, more information is required. You compare markers but mention only one type. What markers dry more slowly? Second, while this is part of the question, you should be aware that correlation between speed of drying and strength of attachment does not imply one causes the other. There are various factors that need to be compared/controlled to provide a proper answer.

thank you especially the components sheet is really helpful  I will read about it and update the question according to what I find , and regarding comparing I am currently comparing exactly one type since I have been using 4  colours at the same time on the board and the only one that stains the board is black thats why I had assumed it has to do with the pigment yet it would also make sense if I buy markers of another type and check since that may shift the focus from pigment to something else

Your question is clear after your last comment (I should have read it more closely). You might emphasize that it is black markers that are the issue, not the brand. You might mention what kind of markerboard you have. Also, when sending comments please use a @ symbol before the username (handle).

Solubility of a pigment in a solvent depends on pigment's polarity. Permanent marker pen usually use a pigment that is unsoluble in polar solvents such as water but soluble in nonpolar solvents such as acetone.

I wouldn't call a dipole moment of 2.88 D not exactly unpolar. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acetone
